# Using Tag property to target Object c#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, tags

I'm trying to create an on event action, that can be reused for a number of objects.
To achieve this I'm storing the name of the target object in the Tag property.
So on event this is triggered:

```
private void ShowDeleteButton(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Duration TimeToTake = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,300));
    DoubleAnimation ShowButton = new DoubleAnimation(0, 104, TimeToTake);
    DoubleAnimation HideButton = new DoubleAnimation(104, 0, TimeToTake);
    (sender as Rectangle).Tag.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, ShowButton);
}
```

Obviously using (sender as button).Tag as the name for the object will not work. So how can I convert the tag property to work as a reference for the target object?

*Note this is WPF*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF, use [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx):

```
var oControl = this.FindName((string)(sender as Button).Tag);
if (oControl != null)
{
    (Rectangle)oControl.BeginAnimation...
}
```

For WinForms, you can find the control by the name that is stored in the Tag:

```
var aoControls = this.Controls.Find((string)(sender as Button).Tag, true);
if ((aoControls != null) && (aoControls.Length != 0))
{
    (Rectangle)aoControls[0].BeginAnimation...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you refer to `UIElement.BeginAnimation` and that sender can be any `UIElement`? If so, then you could simply do:

```
((UiElement)sender).BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, ShowButton);
```